# Blob element to .jpg with multer

Tags: node.js, blob, jpeg

There are lots of info about this and I looked for the solution a few hours and didnt manage to make anything work. I hope you can help me.

I convert the `canvas` to a `blob` element: `blob:null/80883af2-ce7a-49f0-adfa-f8ea2f63c9fc`. I send this to the server with an `ajax` call:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('fname', 'test.jpg');
data.append('data', url);
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/post',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
})
```

I dont manage to save it as a `.jpg`. I tried many things and didnt succeed in anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out how to use `multer` in the end and still used the `base64`- the 'base64Img' package.